# Compiling down to Vanilla JS for NPM package

Tags: javascript, npm

I'm using `npm pack` to export a local package to use in projects.  It uses es6, jsx and other new features.  So when I run `npm install <tarball>` in my new project, it gets unexpected token errors when it tries to import the package.  I tried to having an `prepublish` script that used my webpack config file to compile to `/dist` and then set the package.json's `main` key to `dist/compiledPackage.js` but I wasn't able to import that package either.  I simply want to export my React Component to use in other projects by running `npm install ThatReactComponentTarBall`.  How can I do this?

Comment: Any progress on this?